# Add dynamic column for Ext JS 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3, gridpanel

Is there a way to add a column to a grid panel dynamically in Ext JS 3.4?

I'm trying to add a Row Expander column to my grid panel.

Like the one [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html) (The first plugin)

I can do it by modifying the ui.js and manually adding a column (Like the one in the [code behind](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/grid-plugins.js)), but I'm trying not to.

Any workaround would be highly appreciated!

**Edit**: I found [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134529-How-to-add-columns-in-grid-panel-by-clicking-on-add-column-button-in-extjs-4) for Ext JS 4. Something similar in 3.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.4 you have to use reconfigure method on the grid:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-method-reconfigure